# R display some point in regression plot in different colour

Tags: r

I am making a regression plot of day vs year. There are few values in my plot which I need in some different color. Would really appreciate any help.

```
plot(days$day ~ days$Year, xlab="Time", ylab="No. of break days")
model<-lm(days$day ~ days$Year)
abline(model, col="red", lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run any of the following after the code in your question.

Let's say you want the 5th point in a different color.

```
indexes <- 5
points(days$Year[indexes], days$day[indexes], col = "dodgerblue4")
```

Let's say you want 10 random points in a different color

```
indexes <- sample(length(days$Year), size = 10)
points(days$Year[indexes], days$day[indexes], col = "dodgerblue4")
```

Let's say you want the highest value of `days` in a different color

```
indexes <- which.max(days$day)
points(days$Year[indexes], days$day[indexes], col = "dodgerblue4")
```

Anything you want, you can find the indexes of those points, and plot them in a different color.